# R spread data while preserving order

Tags: r, spread

I've got a dataset that looks like this -

```
dataset = data.frame(Site=c(rep('A',3),rep('B',3),rep('C',3)),MonthYear = c(rep(c('May 19','Apr 19','Mar 19'),3)),Date=c(rep(c('2019-05-31','2019-04-30','2019-03-31'),3)),Measure=c(rep(c('Service','Speed','Efficiency'),3)),Score=runif(9,0,1))
```

My objective is to transform that dataset by using the `spread` function.
However after doing so, I'd like the spread columns to be ordered based on the `Date` column (ascending order).

This would mean that the spread columns are in the following order: `Mar 19`, `Apr 19`, `May 19`

Here's my attempt -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

final = dataset %>% spread(MonthYear,Score)
```

My attempt results in the spread columns being arranged in alphabetical order. And not in chronological order.

Thanks in advance for your inputs

Answer (score 1):

Order the appropriate factor levels and you're done.

```
library(tidyr)

dataset = data.frame(Site=c(rep('A',3),rep('B',3),rep('C',3)),MonthYear = c(rep(c('May 19','Apr 19','Mar 19'),3)),Date=c(rep(c('2019-05-31','2019-04-30','2019-03-31'),3)),Measure=c(rep(c('Service','Speed','Efficiency'),3)),Score=runif(9,0,1))
dataset$MonthYear <- factor(dataset$MonthYear, levels = c("Mar 19", "Apr 19", "May 19"))

spread(dataset, key = MonthYear, value = Score)

  Site       Date    Measure     Mar 19    Apr 19     May 19
1    A 2019-03-31 Efficiency 0.09789678        NA         NA
2    A 2019-04-30      Speed         NA 0.4645101         NA
3    A 2019-05-31    Service         NA        NA 0.89602042
4    B 2019-03-31 Efficiency 0.59516115        NA         NA
5    B 2019-04-30      Speed         NA 0.5208239         NA
6    B 2019-05-31    Service         NA        NA 0.45334636
7    C 2019-03-31 Efficiency 0.93941294        NA         NA
8    C 2019-04-30      Speed         NA 0.5439323         NA
9    C 2019-05-31    Service         NA        NA 0.07971263
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way of doing the same without defining the factor levels beforehand? And instead using the `Date` column as a means of ordering?

Comment: You will have to reorder one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue is that `dataset$MonthYear` is a factor and is not ordered in the way you like.

```
#Find Order by Date column
dLvl <- unique(dataset$MonthYear[order(dataset$Date)])
levels(dataset$MonthYear)
#[1] "Apr 19" "Mar 19" "May 19"
dataset$MonthYear <- factor(dataset$MonthYear, levels = dLvl)
levels(dataset$MonthYear)
#[1] "Mar 19" "Apr 19" "May 19"
final = dataset %>% spread(MonthYear,Score) 
final
# Site       Date    Measure    Mar 19    Apr 19    May 19
#1    A 2019-03-31 Efficiency 0.9928678        NA        NA
#2    A 2019-04-30      Speed        NA 0.1457551        NA
#3    A 2019-05-31    Service        NA        NA 0.6047312
#4    B 2019-03-31 Efficiency 0.4419907        NA        NA
#5    B 2019-04-30      Speed        NA 0.5799068        NA
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way of ordering the columns without explicitly defining the factor levels first? And instead using the `Date` column as a means of establishing this order? I ask because if the time period were to change, then this would mean updating the factor levels every time to ensure the right spread is achieved.

Comment: I believe spread will always put the values depending on the factor levels, so if a new `MonthYear` value were to be entered you would need to update the factor levels again. I adjusted my code so it is a bit more automatic but it relies that `Date` is correctly formatted and consistent

Answer (score 1):

If you convert them to dates you can order the columns based on the order of those dates

```
df <- 
  dataset %>% 
    spread(MonthYear,Score)

col_dts <- as.Date(paste0('01', names(df)), format = '%d%b %y')
df <- df[order(!is.na(col_dts), col_dts)]

df    
#   Site       Date    Measure     Mar 19    Apr 19    May 19
# 1    A 2019-03-31 Efficiency 0.76653679        NA        NA
# 2    A 2019-04-30      Speed         NA 0.0416291        NA
# 3    A 2019-05-31    Service         NA        NA 0.3885358
# 4    B 2019-03-31 Efficiency 0.02538343        NA        NA
# 5    B 2019-04-30      Speed         NA 0.7264234        NA
# 6    B 2019-05-31    Service         NA        NA 0.5128166
# 7    C 2019-03-31 Efficiency 0.50107038        NA        NA
# 8    C 2019-04-30      Speed         NA 0.9013112        NA
# 9    C 2019-05-31    Service         NA        NA 0.3678922
```

Or you could change the factor levels according to the order of the date values

```
new_levels <- 
  with(dataset, {
        mons <- unique(MonthYear)
        ord <- order(as.Date(paste0('01', mons), format = '%d%b %y'))
        mons[ord]})

dataset$MonthYear <- factor(dataset$MonthYear, levels = new_levels)

dataset %>% 
  spread(MonthYear,Score)

#   Site       Date    Measure     Mar 19    Apr 19    May 19
# 1    A 2019-03-31 Efficiency 0.76653679        NA        NA
# 2    A 2019-04-30      Speed         NA 0.0416291        NA
# 3    A 2019-05-31    Service         NA        NA 0.3885358
# 4    B 2019-03-31 Efficiency 0.02538343        NA        NA
# 5    B 2019-04-30      Speed         NA 0.7264234        NA
# 6    B 2019-05-31    Service         NA        NA 0.5128166
# 7    C 2019-03-31 Efficiency 0.50107038        NA        NA
# 8    C 2019-04-30      Speed         NA 0.9013112        NA
# 9    C 2019-05-31    Service         NA        NA 0.3678922
```

You can also use `reorder` with `dcast` (not sure why it doesn't work with spread)

```
library(data.table)

dataset %>% 
  dcast(Site + Date + Measure ~ reorder(MonthYear, -order(Date)), 
        value.var = 'Score')

#   Site       Date    Measure     Mar 19    Apr 19    May 19
# 1    A 2019-03-31 Efficiency 0.76653679        NA        NA
# 2    A 2019-04-30      Speed         NA 0.0416291        NA
# 3    A 2019-05-31    Service         NA        NA 0.3885358
# 4    B 2019-03-31 Efficiency 0.02538343        NA        NA
# 5    B 2019-04-30      Speed         NA 0.7264234        NA
# 6    B 2019-05-31    Service         NA        NA 0.5128166
# 7    C 2019-03-31 Efficiency 0.50107038        NA        NA
# 8    C 2019-04-30      Speed         NA 0.9013112        NA
# 9    C 2019-05-31    Service         NA        NA 0.3678922
```